# @Input accepting generic type

Tags: angular, typescript

I have simple generic class

```
export class MyType<T>{}
```

and now in directive class i'm gonna create @Input field which should be MyType

```
@Input field MyType<>;
```

But intellisense says a MyType<> is wrong type. I know i could extends abstract class to MyType like:

```
export class AbstractType{}
export class MyType<T> extends Abstract{}
```

But as far as i know, lost all generic functions.
Do you have any idea how to do it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Since @Input is a decorator then the syntax is `@Input()` and you're missing the colon after field name, missing the generic type argument as well.

```
@Input() field: MyType<string>;
```